# Operator on Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, operator-theory

I have a question. At the moment, I have a (linear) operator $T:\mathcal{P} \to \mathcal{P}$, where $\mathcal{P}$ are the polynomials in $n$-real variables, with the following two properties:

1. $T$ maps polynomials of total degree $m$ to polynomials of total degree $m$ (for all $m$).
2. The exists a constant $C\ge 1$ with
   $$||Tf||_{\infty,B_r} \le C^{\mathrm{deg} f} \cdot ||f||_{\infty,B_r},$$
   where $B_r$ is the closed ball with respect to the supremums norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $||\cdot ||_{\infty, B_r}$ is the supremums norm on the ball $B_r$.

I would like to know, wether there exist constants $r', D\ge 0$ with
$$||Tf||_{\infty,B_r}\le D \cdot ||f||_{\infty, B_{r'}}, \; \mathrm{ for } \, \mathrm{ all }\, f \in \mathcal{P}.$$

My problem is if it is not the case, I can't find an counterexample, since the statement is correct for all homogeneous polynomials by choosing $D=1, r'=Cr$...

May you could help me?

Best regards,
Dominik

Comment: Is the $n$ for the number of variables the same $n$ as in your condition 1.? Does condition 1. for some $n$ imply condition 1. for other $n'$? Is condition 1. ment to hold for all $n$? Are you refering to the total degree by degree or to another type of degree, say maximum of single variable degrees? Is your operator linear? Please be more precise in formulating your question.

Comment: No, the n in the first condition is universal. The degree is the total degree. And yes the operator is linesr.

Comment: Regarding 1., do you require your operator $T$ to be onto, or it does not matter if it is not surjective from $\mathcal{P}$ to $\mathcal{P}$?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is negative, even for $n=1$. Consider this case, and $T : P \mapsto P'$ the differentiating operator. First, this operator does satisfy your constraint with $r=1$ (and for all $r$, actually): [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_brothers%27_inequality) tells us that for all $P \in \mathbb{R}_n[X]$, $$||P'||_{\infty, [-1,1]} \le n^2 ||P||_{\infty, [-1,1]}$$

with the bound being attained for the [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) $T_n$. You can take $C=3$ and use that $n^2 \le 3^n$ .

---

Assume that you have $D$ and $r'>1$ such that for all $P \in \mathbb{R}[X]$, $||P'||_{\infty, [-1,1]} \le D ||P||_{\infty, [-r',r']}$. Drawing inspiration from the previous case, we look at what happens for Tchebychev polynomials scaled to $[-r', r']$. For all $n$, define $S_n(X) = T_n\Big(\frac{X}{r'}\big)$, which is such that for $x \in [-r', r']$, $S_n(x) = \cos\Big(n \arccos\big(\frac{x}{r'}\big)\Big)$. Then $||S_n||_{\infty, [-r',r']} = 1$. Meanwhile, since we took $r'>1$,the derivative can be expressed very simply on $[-1,1]$:
$$|S_n'(x)| = \Big|\frac{n\sin\big(n \arccos\big(\frac{x}{r'}\big)\big)}{r'\sqrt{1-\big(\frac{x}{r'}\big)^2}}\Big| \ge \frac{n}{r'} \cdot \big|\sin \big(n \arccos\big(\frac{x}{r'}\big)\big)\big|$$

For $n$ large enough, the range of $x \mapsto n \arccos\big(\frac{x}{r'}\big)$ on $[-1,1]$ is an interval with length at least $\pi$, so it includes an element of the form $k\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$, and thus for $n$ large enough, $||S_n'||_{\infty, [-1,1]} \ge \frac{n}{r'}$. This directly contradicts that we should have $||S_n'||_{\infty,[-1,1]} \le D$.

Comment: If you don't want to use the argument about the size of the range of $x \mapsto n\arccos(x/r')$, you can simply evaluate at $x=0$ for odd $n$, in which case you find $|S_n'(0)| = \frac{n}{r'}$. This does not hold for even values of $n$ however

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this differential operator maps polynomials of degree $m$ to polynomials of degree $m-1$ not $m$. Is there an easy way to fix this? Then this would be a nice counterexample.

Comment: I think $P \mapsto P+P'$ still works: you can replicate the reasoning above with the Chebyshev polynomials, and this time it is surjective

Comment: @GhostAmarth are you convinced by the previous comment, or is an addendum needed?

Comment: no its fine; thanks.